# generate a low battery alert programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I want to generate a low battery alert programmatically, same as that will be generated when battery is low..can any one post a sample code how to do it..am aware of ACTION_BATTERY_LOW. but how to use it..? i want to generate a low battery alert even though battery is not low.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295196/how-to-simulate-low-battery-in-android-devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` is a system's broadcast action, so you won't be able to generate it for security reasons - at least not on a "regular" device

Comment: Then is there is any other way to generate low battery alert Martin?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you're trying to do - but if it's just about raising an alarm you could use ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED to monitor the battery state and if it drops under a defined value you can show a custom low-battery-dialogue

Answer (score 2):

Try here:
http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f8/battery-value-in-andriod-22236/

Comment: Link doesn't answer the question; but, is a nice brief example of reading battery level.