# Android terminal--telnet missing commands, receiving this error : KO: unknown command, try 'help'

Tags: android, command-line, terminal, geo

I'm trying to set the coordinates on an emulated device.

```
XXXX-MacBook-XXXXX XXXX$ telnet localhost 5554
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: Authentication required
Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in 
'/Users/XXXXX/.emulator_console_auth_token'
OK
```

The problem is...

```
geo fix 77.9888 34.0000
    KO: unknown command, try 'help'
```

I don't seem to have the geo command

```
help
Android console command help:

    help|h|?         print a list of commands
    auth             use 'auth <auth_token>' to get extended functionality
    avd              control virtual device execution
    quit|exit        quit control session

try 'help <command>' for command-specific help
OK
```

In fact, it looks like most of my commands are missing.

Does anyone know why the commands are missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For amateurs' like me what diego-torres-milano meant :

```
cat /Users/XXXXX/.emulator_console_auth_token
<copy the above contents - auth_token>
telnet localhost <portnumber> (mostly 5554)
auth auth_token
```

Answer (score 35):

You are not authenticated.

Obtain the content of `/Users/XXXXX/.emulator_console_auth_token` and after the OK prompt enter

```
auth <auth_token>
```

Comment: path in this answer is valid for OS X users. for more generic *nix OS (like Linux and OS X) use `~/.emulator_console_auth_token`.