# How to connect to socket server inside emulator from ubuntu?

Tags: android-studio

I use android studio (jetbrains) to develop application.

I try to run socket server, this is a part of code:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9002);
Socket s = ss.accept();
```

There are no errors and looks like server running. I use emulator from android-studio, I run it with green button from studio user interface..

But when I scan opened ports in ubuntu terminal - there is no 9002 port. And it is not possible to connect to it outside the emulator...

Firewall is inactive..

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to set up port redirect from os level - to emulator.

Firstly need to connect to emulator:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

5554 - is an emulator port, it is printed out in console when you run the emulator.

Then you probably will need to authenticate, this is explained here [Android terminal--telnet missing commands, receiving this error : KO: unknown command, try 'help'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700725/android-terminal-telnet-missing-commands-receiving-this-error-ko-unknown-co)

Then you set the redirection:

```
redir add tcp:5000:9002
```

Official documentation is here https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking?hl=it